# A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue, sequence

I'm trying to create an animation sequence with jQuery where one animation starts after the previous one is done. But I just can't wrap my head around it. I've tried to make use of the jQuery.queue, but I don't think I can use that because it seems to have one individual queue for each element in the jQuery array.

I need something like:

```
$('li.some').each(function(){
    // Add to queue
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=100' }, 'fast', function(){
        // Remove from queue
        // Start next animation
    });
});
```

Is there a jQuery way to do this or do I have to write and handle my own queue manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can make a custom [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) to avoid the limitless nesting..

```
var q = $({});

function animToQueue(theQueue, selector, animationprops) {
    theQueue.queue(function(next) {
        $(selector).animate(animationprops, next);
    });
}

// usage
animToQueue(q, '#first', {width: '+=100'});
animToQueue(q, '#second', {height: '+=100'});
animToQueue(q, '#second', {width: '-=50'});
animToQueue(q, '#first', {height: '-=50'});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qDbRm/2/

---

If, on the other hand, you want to perform the same animation for a multitude of elements one after the other then you can use their index to [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay) each element's animation for the duration of all the previous ones..

```
$('li.some').each(function(idx){
    var duration = 500; 
    $(this).delay(duration*idx).animate({ width: '+=100' }, duration);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/qDbRm/3/

Answer (score 2):

The callback of .animate() actually accepts another .animate(), so all you would have to do would be

```
    $(this).animate({ width: '+=100' }, 'fast', function(){
         $(selector).animate({attr: val}, 'speed', function(){
});
    });
```

and so on.

Comment: +1 This is the standard way for chaining animations. Very simple.

Comment: But you can't do that in a loop. Note the 'each'!

Answer (score 1):

You could call the next one recursively.

```
function animate(item) {
    var elem = $('li.some').eq(item);
    if(elem.length) {
        elem.animate({ width: '+=100' }, 'fast', function() {
            animate(item + 1);
        });
    }
}

animate(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not build up a queue?

```
var interval = 0; //time for each animation
var speed = 200;

$('li.some').each(function(){
    interval++;
    $(this).delay(interval * speed).animate({ width: '+=100' }, speed);
});
```

EDIT: added speed param

Comment: Is that reliable? Are you sure that the first animation will be done at that time?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to everybody replying!

I thought I should share the outcome of my question. Here is a simple jQuery slideDownAll plugin that slides down one item at a time rather than all at once.

```
(function ($) {

    'use strict';

    $.fn.slideDownAll = function (duration, callback) {

        var that = this, size = this.length, animationQueue = $({});

        var addToAnimationQueue = function (element, duration, easing, callback) {
            animationQueue.queue(function (next) {
                $(element).slideDown(duration, easing, function () {
                    if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                        callback.call(this);
                    }
                    next();
                });
            });
        };

        return this.each(function (index) {
            var complete = null,
                easing = 'linear';
            if (index + 1 === size) {
                complete = callback;
                easing = 'swing';
            }
            addToAnimationQueue(this, duration / size, easing, complete);
        });
    };

} (jQuery));
```

Not very well test, but anyways.

**Enjoy!!**