# jQuery animation order without callbacks

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a program to illustrate a programmatic solution of ["Towers of Hanoi"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towers_of_hanoi) puzzle, where the disks are represented by absolutely-positioned div-s of different size. To make a move I have a function like this:

```
function move(peg_from, peg_to)
{
//check if the move is valid
//update the game state
//......
//get the div we are moving, calculate it's new position
//move:
the_div.animate({left: new_left, top: new_top}, 500);
}
```

Then a solution may look like this:

```
move(1, 3);
move(1, 2);
move(3, 2);
//... etc...
```

Or recursive, or whatever. In any case, I want to be able to 'eval' any code, defined in terms of move(x, y), not in terms of jQuery's animation or callback functions. The problem is, all animation happens at once, while it needs to be in the calls order. Is there a way to do that?

I have tried adding .delay() to the animations, maybe it could work, but I can't figure out the correct timeouts, anyway. setTimeout() doesn't have any visible effect. Googling reveals some advices of using animation callbacks, but I don't think they are applicable to my case.

Comment: updated answer with working game (*manual*)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer to [A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery/6829667#6829667) matches your problem as well (*with little modifications*)..

You need to [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) your animatios..

```
var q = $({});

function moveToQueue(eg_from, peg_to) {
    q.queue(function(next) {
        //check if the move is valid
        //update the game state
        //......
        //get the div we are moving, calculate it's new position
        //move:
        the_div.animate({left: new_left, top: new_top}, 500, next);
    });
}


// usage
moveToQueue(1, 3);
moveToQueue(1, 2);
moveToQueue(3, 2);
```

---

**Update**

And because i enjoyed it ..
here is a full working solution .. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/nZ4MU/

Comment: By the way, wouldn't it be better to move all the game logic outside of function(next){}, e. g. leave inside the braces only the_div.animate(...); and move everything else one level up? Especially since a call to moveToQueue not necessarily adds animation (the move may be invalid).

Comment: @headcrab yes, you could separate these concerns and only deal with animation when a move has passed all checks

Comment: I have to say I enjoyed watching the animation.  +1 for the completeness of the solution.