# animate christmas ornaments with Jquery ui effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

hi i am playing with jquery ui effects and trying to animate some christmas ornaments. the idea is that they would swing if you hover over them. and swing from the midpoint of the top of the image (the top of the string) like a real ornament and not just the whole image moving back and forth.

what i have so far is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ceeW/

its displaying on click, when i do it on hover they dont work as well or realistically.

this is my first foray into jquery animation and i am not really sure how to proceed next. any help would really be appreciated.

thanks!

Comment: if you minus my question can you please explain why. I am just looking for direction in what to do next to rotate from the center top at the same time while bouncing.

Comment: You need some rotation around the point at the end of the string.  The CSS3 Transform (rotate) is not fully supported in all browsers yet.  Even though it's supported in some browsers, jQuery still will not animate these CSS properties without a plugin.

Comment: I did not down-vote you but your question (what next?) may be considered too general.  SO is typically about solving very specific programming or code problems.

Comment: i see. i was just so new to it... i really just wasnt sure what to ask even

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the plugin from

- http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/02/17/animate-css-transforms-firefox-webkit.html
- add a custom animation queue as in [A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery/6829667#6829667)
- and you end up with animated christmas balls at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9ceeW/8/

---

**update**

updated to allow multiple balls to animate at the same time.. http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/9ceeW/9/

Comment: oh my goodness that is fabulous. exactly what i was trying to do... i will need to pick it apart and figure it out thanks.

Comment: @liz, festive :) (*maybe you should put them behind the text menu, so they do not cause the mouse cursor to flicker.. by setting the `#mainmenu`'s z-index to more than 1.. unless you do not like the effect of the text being over the images when animated..*)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [jQuery Path](https://github.com/weepy/jquery.path) plugin for animating elements along curves. See the author's [demo page](http://weepy.github.com/jquery.path/).

Answer (score 0):

Not really my thing, but you need to add something like this:

```
$('#ball1').click(function () {
    $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:1, distance:60 }, 500);
    $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:1, distance:30 }, 750);
    $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:1, distance:15 }, 1000);
    $(this).effect("bounce", { direction:'left', times:1, distance:5 }, 1250);
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/N7qM9/

Comment: okay i get what you mean here, but this still would bounce the whole div in a horizontal way at the 90 degree plane right? what i am trying to do is get a more natural swing going...

Comment: is there something like rotate and bounce at the same time?

Comment: ahh i see... could work. i will try this before the plugin and see if it can work.

Comment: @hafichuk, a demo in a jsFiddle would be nice because I'm not getting what you're doing here.  It still does not look like it would be doing a rotational swing.

Comment: @Sparky672 http://jsfiddle.net/N7qM9/ It's just liz's code with minor tweaks to the bounce methods. Nothing else.

Comment: Yeah, that's just the same sideways motion.  That's really no good if the string is attached to a fixed point the user can see.

Comment: @Sparky672 As I said, it's not really my thing. And as you said, it's a pretty vague question ;)