# Lots of nested functions can I make this simpler

Tags: jquery

Here is the jQuery I've written to animate some items in a list:

```
$("#titleTile").delay(5000).animate({top: "160px"}, 300, function() {
  $(".tweet_msg.t0").animate({top: 0, height: "show"}, 300, function() {
    $(".tweet_msg.t1").delay(5000).animate({top: 0, height: "show"}, 300, function() {
      $(".tweet_msg.t2").delay(5000).animate({top: 0, height: "show"}, 300, function() {
        $(".tweet_msg.t3").delay(5000).animate({top: 0, height: "show"}, 300, function() { 
          $(".tweet_msg.t4").delay(5000).animate({top: 0, height: "show"}, 300);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Is there a better way to write my code?

Secondly can I wrap it up into a function that I could call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery)

Comment: could you add the html to, to make it easier for use to test? Better yet, you should create a working jsfiddle.net version of what you are trying to do. I can help you better that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other option would be to use a custom queue on a single element.  May be overkill if this is all you are doing.  But if you want to, here is a small example I had created for a previous question:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRawX/2/

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

As far as wrapping it in a function, sure, just wrap it in a function:

```
function something(){
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: How can I add a delay between each animation in the que?