# How to use queue in jQuery animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-animate

I want to increase/decrease the font of and element, then the next element of that class and so forth, for a set of elements as `<div class="test"></div> <div class="test"></div> ....`. I mean

```
step 1: enlarging the first element and returning to normal size
step 2: enlarging the second element and returning to normal size
....
```

My basic code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.test').animate({
               left:50,
               fontSize: "2em"},
               "slow")
               .animate({
               left:-50,
               fontSize: "1em"},
               "slow");
```

This will affect all the elements at once. How can I make a queue to make the changes one by one. Having one enlarged element at a time.

Comment: Why do you have two identical `animate()` methods chained together?  And I don't think `fontSize` is a valid CSS property.  Maybe you want `font-size`.

Comment: @Sparky672 sorry it was a typo. The second `animate` aims to reverse the effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with

```
$('.test').each(function(idx){
    var duration = 1200; // duration for all animations (2 x slow)
    $(this)
         .delay(duration*idx)
         .animate({ left:50, fontSize: "2em" }, 'slow')
         .animate({ left:-50, fontSize: "1em" }, 'slow');
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rz5Es/

---

For more precise control and more freedom on queuing look at my answer at a similar question:
[A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery/6829667#6829667)

Comment: @Sparky672, when not using quoted properties (*as strings*) you are required to use this kind of capitalization (*and removal of dashes*) It is the internal property name.

Comment: So in this case, either `'font-size'` or `fontSize` is acceptable?  Do all dashed property names have an internal DOM counterpart like this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use callbacks and an array of the elements you want to sequentially animate...

```
function animateSequence(elements){
    var element = $(elements).first();
    var originalSize = $(element).css('font-size');

    elements = $(elements).not($(element));

    $(element).animate(
        { fontSize: "2em" },
        "slow",
        function(){
            $(this).animate(
                { fontSize: originalSize },
                "slow",
                function(){
                    if(elements.length > 0)
                        animateSequence(elements);
                }
            )
        }
    );
}

animateSequence($('.test'));
```

If you want to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/xS7X7/

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you are trying to do something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function mycallback(i) {
      var elems = $('.test');
      elems.eq(i).animate({
                   left:50,
                   fontSize: "2em"}, function () {
        mycallback(i + 1 < elems.length ? i + 1 : 0);
      });
    }(0));
});
```

[​DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ78R/1/)

**UPDATE:**

It was an example code, you can change it like this if you want to reverse effects,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    (function mycallback(i) {
      var elems = $('.test');
      elems.eq(i).animate({
                   left:50,
                   fontSize: "2em"}, function () {
        $(this).animate({
               left:-50,
               fontSize: "1em"},
               "slow");
        if (i + 1 < elems.length)
            mycallback(i+1);
      });
    }(0));
});
```

[​UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ78R/2/)

Comment: something like that, but in your example, font will not be resized to normal.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to loop thru all elements and execute `animate` on each of them sequentially, here is sample code to do that recursively

```
function animate_sequential(elems, css, delay, index){
    if(index===undefined) index = 0;
    if(index >= elems.length) return;     
    $(elems[index]).animate(css, delay, function(){
        animate_sequential(elems, css, delay, index+1)
    })
}

animate_sequential($('div'), {'font-size':'30px'}, 500)
animate_sequential($('div'), {'font-size':'15px'}, 500)
```

See it in action http://jsfiddle.net/anuraguniyal/QJc9L/

It can be easily converted to a jQuery plugin, so that you can do `$('div').animate_sequential` and keep same interface as jQuery animate, you can also further enhance it so that it brings back to original css by passing the original css or getting it from element.

Answer (score 0):

So much simpler, readable, and scalable with [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js):

```
$('.test').each(function(i){
    var element = $(this);
    var originalSize = element.css('font-size');

    Frame(function(next){
        element.animate({ fontSize: "2em" }, "slow", next);
    });
    Frame(function(next){
        element.animate({ fontSize: originalSize }, "slow", next);
    });
});
Frame(function(next){
    // add a callback after all the animations have finished
    next();
});
Frame.start();
```