# creating an animation queue in jQuery that contains several DOM elements and animations and firing them sequentially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery)

I have an html/css/js iOS app that currently has several animations that all trigger simultaneously. Not only is this not the desired affect, it's too much for some iOS devices to handle all at once and results in choppy animations.

What I'm looking to do is instead .animate() everything, I'd like to add the animations to a queue and then fire them off sequentially. The challenge here is that the animations are spread throughout the application.

I'm having trouble tracking down how to do this with .queue() — or anything else for that matter...

Comment: If you're using jQuery 1.7+ you can pass a string to [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to specify the queue to which the animation should be added.

Comment: This will solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example on the jQuery site may help some on this issue - where several animations are made on the same element. The example shows the use of queue to order animations all at once or sequentially:

http://api.jquery.com/animate/#example-2

also note MLMs comment above for queueing animations on several elements:

[A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery)