# Running css animation in sequence and WebkitAnimationEnded

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg, svg-animate

I'm trying to animate several SVG line elements in sequence, i followed @Gaby approach here [A non-nested animation sequence in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6829413/a-non-nested-animation-sequence-in-jquery) and used jQuery queue. However my WebkitAnimationEnd is never fired. Maybe it does not work on SVG Elements, but thats not mentioned in the docs:

```
    var q = $({});

    function pushQueue(theQueue, selector, animationprops) {
        theQueue.queue(function(next) {



            $('#' + selector).one("webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend",  function(){
                console.log('Animation ended, calling next..'); 
                next(); 
            } );


            s.select('#' + selector)
                .clone()
                .addClass('path')
                .attr({
                    stroke: "#FFE840",
                    filter: 'none'
                });




        });
    }
```

I added a CodePen below, you can click on the valve just under the p103 pipe to see the effect.

http://codepen.io/yehiasalam/pen/RPbgPz

Comment: Shouldn't it be 'on' and not 'one' ?

Comment: @Ian nop its one https://api.jquery.com/one/, tried on as well just in case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to change. The reason things weren't working before is that you were first `clone`ing the object and *then* adding the `path` class. Here's a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqYVMM).

```
s.select('#' + selector)
     .addClass('path')
     .clone()
     .attr({
        stroke: "#FFE840",
        filter: 'none'
      });
```

Comment: man u're the legend, i spent hours and hours on this, i added the edit http://codepen.io/yehiasalam/pen/LVPadv but for some reason there is a slight delay between each animation, its not like a smooth flow

Comment: im getting lazier, its all css